# How to pass an object property reference to a functon

Tags: python, class, parameters, properties

I want to return an object's property value from a function but I don't know how to pass the property reference to the function

```python
class my_class:
    my_property = 0

c = my_class()
print (c.my_property)

def property_value(o, p):
    return o.p

my_property = 'my_property'
print (property_value(c, my_property))
```

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\teste.py", line 11, in <module>
    print (property_value(c, my_property))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\teste.py", line 8, in property_value
    return o.p
           ^^^
AttributeError: 'my_class' object has no attribute 'p'
```

Tried to search but I can't find the terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin `getattr()` function for this

```
def property_value(o, p):
    return getattr(o, str(p))
    # NOTE: I'm using 'str(p)' here because the property name must be a string!
```

Then you'd call it just as before:

```
print(property_value(c, my_property))
# => 0
```

That said, there's really no need to define a function like `property_value` here because `getattr()` already exists and does exactly the same thing!